# JAVA can invoke the .so file on linux platform?

Tags: java, linux, api

I want to invoke the API provided by a  ".so" file in a JAVA project. Can  JAVA call the .so file on linux platform? Anyone could provide a solution? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

> Can JAVA call the .so file on linux platform?

There are two ways to do this:

- [JNI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/index.html) allows you to declare methods as `native` in Java, and implement then in some other language (typically C or C++) and provide them as ".so" files.  However, you can't do this for any old ".so" file, because Java expects the methods in the ".so" to have JNI specific signatures.
- [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) allows you to call methods in arbitrary native libraries.  You write Java code that provides a "native library declaration" to match the native methods' signatures, and the JNA infrastructure deals with the data type mapping, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via [JNI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html).